# BeautifulSoup | Парсинг текста

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, urllib

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    projects = []
    table = soup.find('div', class_= 'wrap')
    rows = table.find_all('div', class_='listing_wr')
    for i in rows:
        projects.append({
            'title' : i.a.text,
            'Лет': i.super
        })
    for i in projects:
        print(i)


def main():
    parse(get_html('http://kakoysegodnyaprazdnik.ru/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вообщем мне нужно получить все названия и лет праздников с сайта, текст я получил. Но всего-лишь 3, а лет вообще не могу получить помогите пожалуйста(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это немного грубо, но думаю делает, что вам надо:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    projects = []
    rows = soup.find_all('div', class_='main')
    for row in rows:
        spans = row.find_all('span')
        spans_year = row.find_all('span', class_='super')
        print(spans[0].text, spans_year[0].text if spans_year else "")


def main():
    parse(get_html('http://kakoysegodnyaprazdnik.ru/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Суть в том, что я ищу по классу все `div` c названием и потом выбираю `span` с названием праздника - он вроде всегда первый и потом ищу `span` с `class="super"`, который соответствует годам. И если этот `span` есть, то вывоже его на экран.